# normal map in internal and vector transform node

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, normals, geometry

What exactly represent normal output of geometry node in Internal?

As I look at it in cycles, plugging it in color input, I get a correspondence between color on faces and axes (blue , red and green in their "directions").

As it comes to internal, it seems it use a camera space instead of world/object space, as stated here: [Blender Internal Nodes Refactoring (WIP)](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Blender_Internal_Nodes_Refactoring)
but is unclear why the blue channel is then there to be seen.

[image: internal and cycles normals]

More, in internal Geometry node the output from "local" and "view" are pretty the same, and "local" seems not to represent the local "coordinates".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nodes **Vector Transform** for transformation Camera->World and **Vector Curves** for correction Normal ...

[image]

### example blend file:

[image]

Comment: could you edit your picture? because it is so wide it is getting auto resized, which makes it almost unreadable. The crop tool is your friend. All you really need to show is one the nodes. So one image for the BI nodes, and one for cycles.